# Output from noisy optimization in skopt.gp_minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, bayesian, scikit-optimize

When using skopt.gp_minimize on a noisy dataset with unknown variance - is the returned minimum the x-values found for one specific sample of data or the minimum of the surrogate function? And either way - is it possible to specify which one is desired?

I have looked through the documentation but have been unable to find anything describing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the solution with the lowest value of your objective function. To get the expected minimum, use `skopt.expected_minimum()` (documentation [here](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.expected_minimum.html)); more information in [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/1107).

```
from skopt import gp_minimize, expected_minimum
res = gp_minimize(...)
print("Best expected:", expected_minimum(res, ...))
```